# Get parameters are added to the end of every URL

Tags: magento-1.6

I am using Magento 1.6.1.0. The code is running on a server, Linux system. I am accessing the files using ftp connection from the Windows 7 64bit OS.

The problem is that at the end of each url: home page or categories, brands and other pages, I always see this line: ?r=1&width=1536&Height=764, for example: http://www.mywebsite.co.uk/?r=1&width=1536&Height=764 or http://www.mywebsite.co.uk/Locate?r=1&width=1536&Height=764 and etc.

I went to system, configuration, general, web and checked the base urls, there is nothing suspicious. I also tried to revert back the files I was working on in order to find out whether it was my fault. However the problem still exists.

Comment: Thank you. The problem was in Toogas Featured Popup extension as you said. I've found the code which was doing that. The problem is solved!

Comment: I've added my comment as answer. Please add your own answer and accept it to close the issue or accept my answer as solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a development environment for this shop start with disabling all 3th party extensions to see if any of those are causing it. It kind of seems like some testing tool since it's passing along the screen resolution